# Gradient descent in linear regression converges but the trend line is incorrect

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression, optimization, gradient-descent

For the dataset https://physics.info/linear-regression/dash-world.txt, I have been trying to implement linear regression for predicting the men record times as a function of year.
I have used gradient descent to optimize the cost function.
I found that the fastest result I could find by setting the **learning rate to 0.000000045**
There were 2 scenarios that I encountered -

#### Scenario 1 -

Theta was set to [1; 1]. The results obtained were as follows -
[image]
[image]
As you can see clearly see that the prediction function found does not correspond to the actual data.

#### Scenario 2 -

Theta was set to [30; -1000]. The results obtained were as follows -
[image]
[image]

Based on the above observations, I had the following questions -

1. Does gradient descent depend on the starting point for a univariate linear regression?
2. If so, then is there a way to find the most optimum initial values for theta?

**Update** -
Found the problem. To make gradient descent work, the features need to be scaled. Hence, I applied feature scaling using mean normalisation, increased the learning rate and increased the iterations to make it work

Comment: I may be missing something here, but why do you need gradient decent here? Does [maximum likelihood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression) not work for you? This should be a simple matrix calculation - no learning or descending needed. What is the cost function?

Comment: Using normal equations, I easily got the results but I wanted to understand why gradient descent is not working. 
`function J = computeCost(X, y, theta)
    m = length(X);
    J = (1 / (2*m)) * sum(((X*theta) - y)' * ((X*theta) - y));
end`
Gradient descent function - 
`function [theta, J_history] = gradientDescent(X, y, theta, alpha, iterations)
    m = length(X);
    J_history = zeros(iterations, 1);
    for i = 1:iterations
        J_history(i) = computeCost(X, y, theta);
        theta = theta - () * (alpha * (X' * ((X*theta) - y)));
    end
end`

Comment: It will work. You might need more iteration depending on the starting point. but we generally don't control starting point. Just the iteration and the LR.